# Is it possible to join MySQL 8.0 to a cluster of MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, clustering, mysql-8.0, galera, percona-server

I have a MySQL 5.7 (5.7.19-17-57-log Percona XtraDB Cluster) cluster using Galera, but I am in the middle of upgrading to 8.0 -- 8.0.23-14 Percona Server (GPL), Release '14'.  I wasn't sure if it was possible to join the 8.0 box to the clustered 5.7.

Comment: Which flavour of MySQL is this? Percona? Or the one from Codership/Galera?

Comment: Is it possible to join `Server version: 8.0.23-14 Percona Server (GPL), Release '14'`  with a clustered version that is `Server version: 5.7.19-17-57-log Percona XtraDB Cluster (GPL)`

Comment: Search percona.com and https://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/.  Then test it on 3 machines (3 VMs on a single machine should suffice; one could be a garbd).  The likely issues are with the major differences between 5.7 and 8.0, together with how Galera deals with them.

Comment: And please report back on what you discover.  (Consider self-Answering this Question.)

Comment: Ok i will look into this and if it doesn't work.  No issues with updating the post.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to make a Percona MySQL server 8.0 join a Percona XtraDB Cluster, regardless of version. The 8.0 server has to be Percona XtraDB, otherwise it won't have the necessary Galera libraries and bindings.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.